# Finding a group of X objects that is repeating the most

Tags: php

I have a pool of 350 people. Each person was allowed to go out in any given week in the last year.
I also have a weekly list containing the names of the persons that went out.

Task: find which group(s) of X persons went out in the same week, and which of these groups went out most of the weeks (top 10 groups).
Rough observation of the data: people go out between 15 and 30 weeks

What I've done:

- created an array containing all 350 persons
- created an array with the historical data:
  key: week number;
  value: array with the names of the people that went out this week
- created a result array to hold the groups and the count of the weeks they went out

Then, for each combinationX (nCr) of the person's array I intersect with each week of the historical data array. If there is a match, I add this combination to the result array (if this one is already in the array, I increment the count).

I am interested in groups of 7 persons, but there are way too many combinations.

I am looking for a better approach to this problem.

Comment: Please post the code you have developed so far. stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Can you use a database?